# Conversion of CvGet2D

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am having what is follow: img is an IplImage of HeightXWidth. having three channels 
I want to access the three values of the pixel in one image, using another solution rather that the following one that I did:

```
IplImage* img=cvCreateImage(...);
...
CvScalar scalar= cvGet2D(img, i, j); //where i and j are the coordinates of the considered pixel

double v0=scalar.val[0];
double v1=scalar.val[1];
double  v2=scalar.val[2];
```

My idea is to get rid of the OpenCV dependency and change it in another way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking hear. What exactly do you wish to convert it to?

Comment: @Paddyd I have edited my question with more edits and explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CV_IMAGE_ELEM](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#Howtoaccessimagepixels) to access pixel with x,y co-ordinates like

```
CV_IMAGE_ELEM( image_header, elementtype, y, x*N+C )
```

For example if you want to access second channel of IplImage *img(3 channel) with i,j you can have

```
CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, y, (x * 3) + 1))
```

Or use below method to access r,g,b pixel value

```
int col, row, z;
     uchar b, g, r;
     for( y = 0; row < img->height; y++ )
     {
       for ( col = 0; col < img->width; col++ )
       {
         //for( z = 0; z < img->nChannels; z++ )
         //{
         //   c = img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * img->nChannels + z];
         //}
         b = img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * 3]
         g = img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * 3 + 1];
         r = img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * 3 + 2];
       }
     }
```

For more details see this  Stack-overflow  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535364/how-do-i-access-a-pixel-in-opencv)

Comment: This is linked with OpenCV and I don't want to introduce to my program OpenCV. Can you give me another idea?

Comment: If you don't want to include OpenCV how could you load image to memory?. Do you have any other method like file read.